# Require Public Key Authentication for a particular user in OpenSSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, sshd

How may I configure my OpenSSH server to require public key authentication for a particular (regular, non-root) user? All other users may log in via password as usual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Match User attie
    AuthenticationMethods publickey
```

Note that `Match` sections need to be at the end of the config file...

Don't forget to reload the SSH server:

```
systemctl reload ssh
```

---

> ```
>  AuthenticationMethods
>         Specifies the authentication methods that must be successfully completed for a
>         user to be granted access.  This option must be followed by one or more comma-
>         separated lists of authentication method names.  Successful authentication
>         requires completion of every method in at least one of these lists.
>
>         For example, an argument of "publickey,password publickey,keyboard-interactive"
>         would require the user to complete public key authentication, followed by
>         either password or keyboard interactive authentication.  Only methods that are
>         next in one or more lists are offered at each stage, so for this example, it
>         would not be possible to attempt password or keyboard-interactive
>         authentication before public key.
> ```

Comment: Match lines must appear at the end of sshd_config.

Comment: Thanks, I've added it to my answer for completeness